Trying to run PowerShell script through C# Winforms but automation namespace is missing. How to reference the automation?
In the nuget package manager console, I typed
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK 

and it installed it fine. But still the automation is missing.
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

I'm using Visual Studio, C#, Winforms, .NET 4.8

Try dotnet add package Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK, Install-Package is cursed

Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK is not compatible with .NET Framework. It works only with .NET 8.0
